# What is the difference in plotting ROC curve with probability scores vs binary decisions

Tags: roc

As the title reads what is the difference? Plotting the ROC w.r.t probability scores gives the stair cased version.

But in my opinion I find that using binary decision is better because the ROC curve is just a summary of the different confusion matrices w.r.t different thresholds. And the confusion matrix shows the binary decisions.

Is their an advantage or certain situation where plotting the ROC curve with the prob.scores is better than the binary decisions?

Comment: Please read about proper scoring rules. There is a good answer here, and the links within that answer (and the links within those, especially Harrell's blog) are worth reading: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/proper-scoring-rule-when-there-is-a-decision-to-make-e-g-spam-vs-ham-email.

Comment: I don't see how this is about proper scoring rules in the sense that is described in the link. Scikit user guide under chapter 3.3 -  Metrics and scoring: quantifying the quality of prediction, states "This function (roc_curve) requires the true binary value and the target scores, which can either be probability estimates of the positive class, confidence values, or **binary decisions** "  Hence why I was wondering what the difference and the advantages are.

Answer (score 2):

How do you go from probabilities to binary decisions? The default choice is to use a threshold of 0.5 but maybe a threshold of 0.3 or 0.7 would have given better results (depending on you metric). The ROC curve gives you more information as it allows to see the results for each probability threshold.

Usually you set some metric to optimize (F1 score for example) and you set the threshold based on this metric. Then you plot the confusion matrix and any other metric that is useful to you

Comment: I understand that the probabilty is what determines the binary classification but as I said what is the difference? The ROC gives result based on different thresholds, as you said, but then it shouldnt matter if I choose the curve based on the predicted probabilties or the binary classes.

Comment: Colud you clarify a bit more "choose the curve" and "binary classes" ?

Comment: Binary classes = when the output is 1 or 0. I use a logistic regression model which the output can be in form av decision function, probabilites or predictions (i.e. 1 or 0).

Hence, I was wondering what the difference is when I plot the ROC in terms of probabilites or the output in terms of predicitons (the binary classes).

Comment: Could you post some code of what you are actually comparing? ROC curves don't have a meaning to me if you give it your thresholded predictions instead of your probabilities. To my knowledge ROC curves are plotted using the various thresholds you could set on your probability ouput. If you pass it the thresholded values  nothing should vary (or maybe by default you would have 3 points : one if you set everything to 0, one that actually represent  the score of your model with the default threshold of 0.5, and one if you set everything to 1)

Comment: Okey, so to make it simple, why wouldnt this work:1. vary the threshold at which you'd predict either a 0 or 1
2.At different thresholds compute the true positive rate (TPR) and false positive rate (FPR)
Plot TPR vs FPR 3. Plot the graph.

Comment: To me what you describe is exactly what a ROC curve is (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic : "The ROC curve is created by plotting the true positive rate (TPR) against the false positive rate (FPR) at various threshold settings")

Comment: The thing that I am confused about is why I could provide the binary outcome in the roc_curve() method in scitkitlearn and still get a curve. To me this would be the most logical way as its only to compare 1s and 0s to calculate TP,TN,FP,FN and so on.

Comment: You're right, you only need 1s and 0s to compute TP, TN, FP, FN and therefore TPR and FPR. However by feeding the binary versionof the output you will get only one point (one pair TPR,FPR) not a full ROC curve. If you give it the probabilities it will compute (TPR, FPR) for each threshold (hence the curve) and you get to choose which one is best for you. However if you give the binary output the ROC curve won't be able to give you any valuable information over than the (TPR, FPR) you get when using the threshold  that was used to convert probas into binaries

Comment: Yes, know I understand it better. Thank you!